# def function to compare two strings

Tags: python-3.x

we need to define a function that compares two strings and if they are different we want to know the index. the problem is that no matter what insert we use we always get -1 even when they are not the same.

```python
def mutation_detector(seq1,seq2):
    if DNAval(seq1) and DNAval(seq2) == True:
        if len(seq1) == len(seq2):
            for i in range(0, len(seq1)) and range(0, len(seq2)):
                if seq1[i] != seq2[i]:
                    return(i)
                else:
                    return(-1)
        else:
            return('Wrong input')
    else:
        return('Wrong input')

print(mutation_detector('ATCGGGTA','ATCGGCTA'))
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this line: for i in range(0, len(seq1)) and range(0, len(seq2))... since both seq1 and seq2 are already established to have the same length, why not just range over seq1?

Comment: Hi Michelle - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below an answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. ***Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question.*** If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're using `and` wrong and have some basic Logic errors I think:

and doesn't say "do A and B" but rather"if A is True and B is True"

My attempt at fixing it is as follows:

```
if DNAval(seq1) and DNAval(seq2): 
    if len(seq1) == len(seq2): 
        for (i, (elem1, elem2)) in enumerate(zip(seq1, seq2)): 
            if elem1 != elem2: 
                    return i
        return -1
```

Your if-else in the loop always returns in the First loop iteration: it takes the first two chars and compares them; are they equal? No -> return -1

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the logic, it begins comparing strings. If the two letters are the same, it goes for the ELSE (because they are not different) and ends the routine after checking only the first letter.

You only want the routine to return -1 if it makes it all the way through the for loop without returning an index number. So,

Change as below:

```
def test(seq1, seq2):
    if len(seq1) == len(seq2):
        for i in range(0, len(seq1)):
            if seq1[i] != seq2[i]:
                return(i)
        return(-1)
    else:
        return('Wrong input')

print( test('Hello1', 'Hello2'))
print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are returning -1 on the first time you run through the for loop, because the else-clause is immediately entered.
Use the else clause with the for loop itself instead.
For example:

```
def compare_strings(seq1, seq2):
    if len(seq1) == len(seq2):
        for i in range(0, len(seq1)):
            if seq1[i] != seq2[i]:
                return i
        else:
            return -1
    else:
        return 'Wrong input'
```

(mind you, raising a custom exception might be better than returning "Wrong input" here...)

Answer (score 0):

```python
def comp_string(string1,string2):
  if len(string1)!=len(string2):
    return "length not equal"
  else:
    for i in range(len(string1)):
      if string1[i] != string2[i]:
        return i
    return "equal"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it

```
def mutation_detector(seq1, seq2):
    if not DNAval(seq1) or not DNAval(seq2) or len(seq1) != len(seq2):
        return "Wrong input"  # maybe raise ValueError if DNAval fails instead?

    for index, (base1, base2) in enumerate(zip(seq1, seq2)):
        if base1 != base2:
            return index

    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
It will return index when unable to compare otherwise it will compare two character and to print equal again compare it with length of string.

```
def mutation_detector(seq1,seq2):
    count=0
    if len(seq1) == len(seq2):
         for i in range(0, len(seq1)) and range(0, len(seq2)):
               if seq1[i] != seq2[i]:
                    return i
               else:
                    count=count+1
   if count==len(seq1):
         return 'Equal'
print(mutation_detector('ATCGGCTA','ATCGGCTA'))
```